# alternative to 'send email to document library' in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, incoming-email

having removed the functionality of document libraries to receive an email from outlook client and having removed the Site Inbox, what is the easiest and most effective way to have emails into a document library? it is not practical to save the email in the library

Comment: You could use Office 365 Groups where shared mailbox emails could be saved to document library or you can use Flow to copy files to the library

Comment: what if the site has been already created as a standalone site collection? how do you 'link' an existing site with a O365group email service?

Comment: You can't convert the existing site yet.  MS has a plan to launch this later this year.  If you already have a site collection, Flow would do the job, but you will need to create an email address.

Comment: flow would do the job how? from inbox to a certain sharepoint location? why do I need to create an email address?